# How bad is it to freeze vegetables in glass for a maximum of 4 weeks?

Tags: freezing, vegetables

How bad is it to freeze vegetables, like broccoli, spinach, or cauliflower in glass pots? I am using glass pots from IKEA that are airtight. I will be storing them for no more than 4 weeks. How does it compare to vacuumed zip lock type bags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main effect that reduces the quality of food that is stored in the freezer is freezer burn. This is basically dehydration, caused by the very dry air in the freezer. Any container that seals airtight prevents this from happening, so your vegetables should stay good.

With glass containers, you may have to be careful to prevent them from cracking. If there is a lot of liquid in the food you want to freeze, you have to take care to leave enough empty space in the container to allow the water to expand as it freezes. With containers that have a very rigid lid (like jars with a metal lid) it can be a good idea to freeze with the lid placed only loosely on top, and then tighten the lid as soon as everything is frozen, to avoid having a lot of pressure inside the jar from the expanded water.

Comment: What about nutrition? Does the airtight containers keep the nutrion value or will it decrease?

Comment: What Nutrients do you mean? As far as I know freezing doesn't destroy any nutrients. However, freezing can destroy cell walls (the reason leafy greens go limp after freezing and thawing) so this probably makes it easier for some vitamins to get lost (washed away) during cooking after thawing, but I don't know for sure.